# In a web MVC framework, who has the responsibility to show 404 page?

Tags: model-view-controller

In a web MVC model, which class/object has the responsibility/function to call 404 page? Why does it has the responsibility? I think it's the Router, but I'm asking just in case.

```
$router->show_404("Unable to find controller.");
```

Also, should a 404 page be a view or just a template? What's the standard practice here?

-- Update, makes things much clearer --

If for example, we agree that the the `Router` class holds the function/responsibility to call 404 page, should we then inject `Router` object to the controller we instantiated so that each controller can use the `Router` object to call 404s? Or should I create a custom class built to display 'special pages' like Error/404s?

Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on the situation.

If it's due to an invalid route, then it can either be handled by the router itself or you can have a default route which points to a 404 handler.

If it's due to a valid route receiving invalid data (`/user/JohnDoe`, but John Doe isn't known to the system), then the 404 would have to be initiated by the handler for that route.

Once the 404 is triggered, I tend to prefer light, fast pages reporting it, but there are plenty of sites out there which will, e.g., do an approximate-match search and return a list of "did you mean one of these things?"  I'm not sure which way I would call "standard practice" in either case, unless you're talking about REST APIs, which would normally send a minimal response, since they're aimed at machine-readability, so there's not a lot of point in asking a question that only a human could answer.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer something like this in the "driver":

```
try
{
  $router->handleRequest($request);
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
  $view = new View('error');
  echo $view;
}
```

A 404 is just another exception handled by the `catch` block. You could always have a specific 404 exception if you want to do something special with it. Or you could have a generic "http exception" that includes some status code that would indicate which template to use.

Comment: what if the 404 is only found out after we load the controller?

Comment: @rickchristie, my `handleRequest` function assumes everything happens in there. The important thing is that at some point inside that `try {}` block the controller's action gets called. If the controller's action wants to simulate a 404 due to, say, an invalid id, then it just throws that exception. (Most likely, it will be the same exception that the router would throw if a route wasn't found, but that's just a minor implementation detail.)

Comment: your idea is very interesting! Thanks a lot for the input :)

Answer (score 0):

It is the responsibility of the View, to report the error. And view code need to be designed accordingly to report the meaningful error messages

```
<web-app ...> 

  <error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/WEB-INF/pages/404_error.jsp</location>
  </error-page>

</web-app>
```